# Elastic Beanstalk email alert when application is red?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In the environment settings it seems like notifications can only be turned on for all environment changes. Is there anyway that I can be emailed ONLY when the application becomes red?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common reason for the elasticbeanstalk environment to become red is when the ELB does not find any healthy backend instance to work with. You could set a CloudWatch alarm on the healthy instance count behind the ELB and trigger an email alert when the incident occurs.

[This link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_AlarmAtThresholdELB.html) would help you in setting up the required alarms.

Comment: Thanks. I thought elastic beanstalk was supposed to automatically create new instances when needed?

Comment: Yes it does so as per the auto-scaling policy set on it but only till the maximum limit on the number of instances that it can launch. When there are no healthy backend instances, it turns red.

Comment: I had it set to the default (4 max), but there was only ever 1 EC2 instance live.

Comment: What was the trigger point in terms of CPU, IO, memory,etc. set for the auto-scaling group ?

Comment: It’s the default: Scale based on Average network out
Add instance when > 6000000
Remove instance when < 2000000

Comment: So then the metrics would not have met the above scaling condition and hence Elasticbeanstalk did not launch a new instance while the only instance went out of service resulting in the environment to turn red.